# Split Function using an Excel row as delimiter

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, split

I have a used column and I would like to create an array that would split this column into several items using cell/row as a delimiter.

Something like: `MyArray = Split(Excel.Workbooks(X).Worksheets(X).UsedRange.Columns(X), Row)`

I get `Type Mismatch` error.

Is it possible or are there any workarounds?

Comment: It's rare that I don't undestand a question asked, but I don't understand this one.

Comment: if you are looking for delimeter apart from cell means, that itself separated/splited, you can copy/paste like how you want. if you want to separate the cell content means you can check my answer.

Comment: MyArray = Excel.Workbooks(X).Worksheets(X).UsedRange would already be split out as this would read each cell into the array?

Comment: If you have used Split function before, and know what a delimiter is, then I am sorry, but my question is as clear as it can be.

Comment: If you want to split based on each row just read it into an array and dont bother using the split function at all?

Comment: Yes 99moorem, I thought about that, but if it is possible to do it through Split function using just one line of code it would be much more efficient, don`t you think?

Comment: @LevySchiavetti Your question is unclear because you don't provide expected input and output in the form of screengrabs or typing out what the worksheet should look like before and after.  Nonetheless, I took a stab at clarifying what the `Split()` function can do.

Comment: MyArray = Excel.Workbooks(X).Worksheets(X).UsedRange this is one line of code? I have 2 thoughts about this 1) I think the split function would be less efficient in terms of CPU time 2) I do not believe you can split on row like this, only by reading it into an array

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax for the `Split()` function is `Split([String], [Delimiter String])`.  To accomplish this in your example, it would be best to create a loop:

http://www.homeandlearn.org/the_split_function.html

```
Sub SplitIt()
    Dim LastRow As Long, txt As String, i as Integer, CurRow as Long, MyArray as Variant, ws as Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Name of Sheet")
    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For CurRow = 1 to LastRow
        MyArray = Split(ws.Range("A" & CurRow).Value, "[Delineation String]")
        For i = 0 to UBound(MyArray)
            ws.Cells(CurRow, i + 2).Value = MyArray(i)
        Next i
    Next CurRow
End Sub
```

For example if column A had three words seperated by a "space" and you used the "space" as your "Delineation String" then you would get:

```
           A                B        C         D
1  Alpha Bravo Charlie    Alpha    Bravo    Charlie
2  Delta Echo Foxtrot     Delta    Echo     Foxtrot
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you are looking for split cell contents and want it somewhere in your sheet/workbook.

```
Sub split_1()
Dim myarray() As String
Dim str As String
str = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
'str = "this,sentence,seperated,by,comma"
   myarray = Split(str, ",")

   For i = LBound(myarray) To UBound(myarray)
      Debug.Print myarray(i) 'here you can copy to other cells/sheets, etc.,
    Next
End Sub
```